# Images not displaying on node.js presented webpage

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a node.js server with the following code:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    index = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html');

var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(index);
});

app.listen(80);
```

When I use an  tag in index.html, no images will show:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="settings.gif" />
    </body>
</html>
```

The image is in the same directory as the server.js file and index.html

Edit: Images will show if I use a full URL to another site. Example:

`<img src="http://yellowicons.com/wp-content/uploads/Gear-Icon-2.png" />`

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you may decide to separately create a **public/images** directory beneath and copy the settings.gif as well as any other images into the image directory that can be publicly viewable.

Next you will need to make known to node where the static reference for the public directory is by adding these 2 lines into node.js

```
var publicDir = require('path').join(__dirname,'/public');
app.use(express.static(publicDir));
```

After which, the image could be tagged in the html as

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="images/settings.gif" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using absolute path. In case of failure, keep the image file in `public/images` directory. and use this address:

```
<img src="http://localhost:3000/images/Heading.png" />
```

Comment: This would only work if the server was running locally correct?

Also, what is the reason of port 3000?

Comment: yes, It answers the question for local servers, and 3000 is just an example port number, you should use your own port (if any defined)

Answer (score 1):

Before access image fine html static page we have to add static folder location in the nodejs middleware using `app.use()` method

```
staticPages 
  | - image.png
  | - index.html
```

**code:**

*server.js*

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "staticPages")));
```

*index.html*

**before server start:** `<img src="./image.png" />`

**after server start:** `<img src="http://localhost:3000/image.png" />`

Answer (score 0):

I guess your server doesn't know where your images are, I don't see where your code specifies that. I suggest you use nodejs with express to handle all your routes, just google it and have tons of examples.
Good luck